# My custom Class from my private library isn't recognized

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I have an private library called "CSVBuilder" in a Symfony project. Let's see how it is in my project.

- MyProject

  - vendor

    - mypackage

      - CsvBuilder.php
      - composer.json

The content of the `CsvBuilder.php` looks like :

```
<?php

namespace MyPackage;


class CSVBuilder
{
// etc..., the behavior of the class doesn't really matter

   public function __construct($fieldSep = "\t", $eol = "\n", $defVal = "", $utfEncode = false)
    {
        $this->defVal = $defVal;
        $this->fieldSep = $fieldSep;
        $this->eol = $eol;
        $this->utf8Encode = $utfEncode;
    }
}
```

And the `composer.json` of my private library is very short, here it is :

```
{
    "name": "mypackage",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "mypackage\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the namespace. Alright. Nothing special from now.

So in another file, in a randon Controller `SiteController.php`, I have this obvious code :

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use MyPackage\CSVBuilder as csv;
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $builder = new csv(); // this line crashed 
    }
```

It creates this erreur :

> Error
>   Class 'MyPackage\CSVBuilder' not found

It looks like a namespace problem, but I don't know what's wrong with my code. Everything sounds pretty okay for me.

Of course, in `SiteController.php`, I tried to replace `use MyPackage\CSVBuilder as csv;` by `use MyPackage as csv;`, but it trigerred the same problem =>

> Error
>   Class 'MyPackage' not found

Any suggestion please ? :)

Comment: Is `mypackage` properly included in your main `MyProject/composer.json` and has composer generated the appropriate autoloaders for `mypackage`…?

Comment: Yes, `mypackage` is included in my main `MyProject/composer.json`.

"and has composer generated the appropriate autoloaders for mypackage", sorry I don't know what do you mean about that :'(

Comment: It looks like case sensitivity problem - try use `MyPackage` as namespace name in `psr-4` autoloading config.

Comment: it can't be a case sensitivity problem, because every single name/variable/property/folder name/file name is in lower case (except the CsvBuilder class).

Comment: The keys in the `psr-4` mapping section are not directory names. These are namespace prefixes that are case-sensitive. So you need to change it to `MyPackage\\` and probably run `composer dump-autoload` afterwards.